# Can I create key binding for my snippet in Geany?

Tags: geany

I created a snippet in Geany. Can I bind a key for this snippet?

For example, binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to the snippet `bf=\\textbf{%cursor%}`.

I knew key binding from menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Keybindings*. But it just allows binding a key to the listed functions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `[Keybindings]` part in file `snippets.conf`.

**Attention**: these keybindings can be overridden by Geany's configurable keybindings, i.e. keybindings from menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Keybindings*.

In the case you want using this way to create a keyboard shortcut for a snippet, but it is already in the Geany's configurable keybindings, you need to change this keyboard shortcut in the Geany's configurable keybindings.

Comment: Can you provide the actual input for the example shortcut (Ctrl + B)? (And also test if it actually works - I couldn't get Alt + 8 to work, not even after restarting Geany.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Since `Ctrl+b` is assigned to `Go to matching brace` in Geany's configurable keybindings. You need change it or leave it blank. Then create snippet `bf=\\textbf{%cursor%}`, then put line `bf=<Ctrl>b` in the `[Keybindings]` part. `Alt+8` not work for me, too.

Comment: Attention, typing combination of shortcut in Geany's format. For example, using `<Ctrl>b`, **not** using `Ctrl+b`